# HTML form post's null values/keys through EMAIL

Tags: html, asp.net, email, c#-4.0, request.form

I am **mailing** html body with two buttons APPROVE/REJECT. Now when I click Approve through EMAIL body, the HTML form posts hidden fields to the aspx page where I am fetching the values through Request.Form[]. Here on aspx page when I try to catch the values, its shows keys are empty. It doesn't retrieve any value from POST. Please help!

HTML CODE (**This is mailed to recipient**):

```
  <table>
  <tr>
   <td>
      <form id="Approve"    action="http://localhost:58177/LMS/WEBFORMS/frmGetApprovalStatus.aspx"
                method="post">
                <input type="submit" value="Approve" style="font: bold 15px Arial; text-decoration: none;
                    background-color: #228B22; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px; border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
                    border-right: 1px solid #333333; border-bottom: 1px solid #333333; border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;" />
                <input type="hidden" name="Approval_flag" value="xyz" />
                <input type="hidden" name="Leadno" value="17" />
                <input type="hidden" name="username" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="mstrid" value="abc" />
                <input type="hidden" name="request_remarks" value="def" />
                <input type="hidden" name="UNIQUE_ID" value="pqr" />
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form id="Reject" action="http://localhost:58177/LMS/WEBFORMS/frmGetApprovalStatus.aspx"
                method="post">
                <input type="submit" value="Reject" style="font: bold 15px Arial; text-decoration: none;
                    background-color: #FF0000; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px; border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
                    border-right: 1px solid #333333; border-bottom: 1px solid #333333; border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;" />
                <input type="hidden" name="Approval_flag" value="xyz" />
                <input type="hidden" name="Leadno" value="17" />
                <input type="hidden" name="username" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="mstrid" value="abc" />
                <input type="hidden" name="request_remarks" value="def" />
                <input type="hidden" name="UNIQUE_ID" value="pqr" />
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

ON ASPX PAGE :

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["Leadno"]) )
            {
                Response.Write("<u>Values using Form Post</u><br /><br />");
                Response.Write("<b>Leadno:</b> " + Request.Form["Leadno"]);
            }
```

Thanks in advance!!!